# Onclick of the button, show the data in console that is fetched by api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, javascript-objects

---

### Heading

```
import react, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => json(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(data);
        }}
      >
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

the if i try to code the same thing taking a function  then it is displaying error

Comment: So, what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the `data` in a state variable to access them through your component:

```
import react, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './styles.css';

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(data);
        }}
      >
        submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```